# How to send email notification using airflow that contains attachment?

Tags: python, airflow

Hello everyone I am new to airflow and would require some help here
As of now 2 task are defined

t1=SSHOperator(task_id='get_count', ssh_conn_id=env_key, command= f ' path/count.py,dag=dag)
t2=emailoperator(task_id='email',to='',html_content=None,subject='count',dag=dag)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/email/index.html Is this answer your question?